# Error when executing report with Data-driven subscription due to invalid parameter value

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

After the report is executed by data-driven subscription, the following error is thrown to the Reporting Services LogFile:

**ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidReportParameterException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidReportParameterException: Default value or value provided for the report parameter 'customer' is not a valid value.;**

If I execute the report manually, it works completely fine since the `customer` parameter value is static.

Does anyone know a solution for this when values are dynamic from the data-driven subscription query results?

Comment: What do you mean by manually? On the report server or debug mode in BIDS? What did you specify for the customer parameter in the subscription?

Comment: @DominicGoulet I'm sorry for the ambiguity. I meant executing the report in the report manager selecting/passing values to the report parameters

Comment: And what value do you give to the 'customer' parameter? You checked the checkbox to use default value? Assigned a static value? Got the value from a query?

Comment: @DominicGoulet I am not using any default value. I have available values coming from a query and I usually select one of them in the dropdownlist. I do the same in the subscription, assigning that parameter to the relevant column of the query

Comment: Then in that case, when the query get executed, the returned value that you assign to the customer parameter is not a valid value, which is often because it returns NULL and NULL was not a valid value for your parameter. It can also be that no rows are returned by your query. Most often, this happen with queries that use time related components, such as getdate(), which is usually run overnight and not in the day as you test it.